# Unable to run headless chrome using dockerfile for (cucumber , java , maven project)

Tags: java, docker, maven, google-chrome-headless, webdrivermanager-java

I am trying to create a dockerfile and image for CI/CD.
My Project stack is : Maven, Cucumber BDD, java , junit, using bonigarcia's webdrivermanager dependency in pom.

We were able to run "hello world" print statement using dockerfile (mentioned below), but when we try to run chrome and try to export chromebrowser to location:
[image]

it gives this below
**Error:**

[image]

[image]

My Dockerfile is

```
enter code here`enter code here` FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine 
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash
ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.3.9
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \&& curl -fsSLhttp://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
| tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \&& ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
RUN mvn -version
#FROM alpine:latest
#RUN apk update
#RUN apk fetch openjdk8
#RUN apk add openjdk8
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"
RUN java -version
RUN javac -version
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pwd
RUN mvn test
#CMD ["mvn" , "test"]
```

My Step Definition

```
@Given("User navigate to homepage")
public void userNavigateToHomepage() throws InterruptedException {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true"); //THIS will surpress all logs expect INFO
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF); // this could be used to stop INFO logging in chrome driver
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
options.setHeadless(true);
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model, MUST BE THE VERY FIRST OPTION
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
    options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
    options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
    options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--incognito");
    options.merge(cap);
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    logger.info("......Hello world.......");
    logger.info("......Hello world.......");
    logger.info("launching url");
    driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
    String actual = driver.getTitle();
    logger.info("Title of the page is :" + actual);
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("admin");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    logger.info(".......Closing the test now......");
    logger.info(".......Closing the test now......");
    logger.info(".......Closing the test now......");
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

POM FILE

```
enter code here <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>TestDocker</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>4.3.0</cucumber.version>
    <selenium.version>3.141.5</selenium.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>TestRunner</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

i have tried solution from various links but nothing worked. Could someone please guide me.
Thanks in advance